# Почему не происходит подстановка плейсхолдеров в SQL запрос (mysql и php)

Tags: pdo, placeholder

Помогите разобраться почему не проходит запрос.
Судя по ошибке не происходит подстановки плейхолдеров. Если плейходеров больше одного то выходит ошибка, если правильно понял то получился запрос ..? WHERE ? = ?... Ошибка:

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
>   violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '? WHERE ? = ?' at line 1 in
>   D:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\core\ClassModel.php:48 Stack trace: 
>   D:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\core\ClassModel.php(48):
>   PDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM :...')
>   D:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\core\core.php(47):
>   core\ClassModel->countField('object', 'id', '33') 
>   D:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\index.php(24): Core::routerUrv()  {main} 
>   thrown in D:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\core\ClassModel.php

```
$tableName = 'object';
$column = 'id';
$searchValue = '33';

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM :tablename WHERE :column = :value';

$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':tablename' => $tableName, 'column' => $column, ':value' => $searchValue));
return $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
```

Comment: во первых имя таблицы и имя колонки невозможно подставить через плейсхолдер, вписывайте явно в текст. (через плейсхолдер можно вписать только то, что может быть представлено в запросе как переменная или значение колонки. во вторых уберите знак $ из имени плейсхолдера и в третьих при execute у ключей массива не надо писать двоеточия в начале

Comment: Понял, спасибо! В примерах видел что не подставляют в имена таблиц и колонок,  но придал значения. А в статьях явно не прописано.